# When you use a string variable to set a properties name why would it ever use the name of the variable itself instead?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

We are using some new ECMAScript stuff so I don't know if that's what's going on. Basically I do:

```
var key = "foo";
var obj = { key: "abc" };
```

and it created and obj.key property instead of an obj.foo property.

[image]

Comment: This is how JavaScript worked since the beginning...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a property name, not an expression that can be a variable.

In ES6, you can make it an expression:

```
var obj = { [key]: "abc" };
```

Comment: Whoa dude. That worked. I am completely confused about what just happened though. What do the brackets do?

Comment: @dolphonebubleine: It makes the interpreter evaluate the character sequence `key` instead of taking it literally.

Comment: So it is an ecmascript thing? Is there a name for this type of behavior so I can read more about it? edit - nm. Just realized what is going on. duh. It's creating a literal and not using my key variable.

Comment: @dolphonebubleine: The ES6 feature is called "computed property names".